# Плавно скрыть и показать элемент списка

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

У меня есть список, при нажатии на кнопку часть списка прячется, другая же наоборот появляется. Но все это не красиво, как только спрятал елемент, резко на его место влево съезжают остальные елементы... Как можно сделать плавный сдвиг?
вот код, который использую:

```js
var newSelection = "";
$("#category a").click(function() {
  $("#category a").removeClass("current");
  $(this).addClass("current");
  newSelection = $(this).attr("rel");
  $(".category").not("." + newSelection).slideUp(200);
  $("." + newSelection).slideDown(300);
});
```

```css
.menu{margin-right: 7%; margin-left: 7%;text-align: center; min-width: 1200px;font: 12px/1.5em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, "Arial Narrow";color:#a5a5a5;}
.menu img{border: 1px solid #d5d5d5; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;background:#FFFFFF;padding:10px;}
.menu img:hover{border: 1px solid #A9CF54;box-shadow:0 0 5px #A9CF54;}

.menu ul{text-align: center;}
.menu li{float: left;margin: 0 12px 20px 0;overflow: hidden;width: 245px;padding:5px; color: green; text-align: center;}
#category {margin-right: 7%; margin-left: 7%; color: red;}
#category h1{color: grey; font-size: 350%;margin-left: 0;}
#category a { padding: 2px 6px; border: 1px solid #A74C10; }
#category a:hover, #category a.current { background: #A74C10; color: white; }

.menu h1{
height: 40px;
}
```

HTML:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не смог вставить нормально код, сделал скрин...
Я загружаю инфу из базы и вывожу списком. Мотом по категориям скрываю нужные и наоборот

Comment: Может вам поможет `transition` - _Устанавливает эффект перехода между двумя состояниями элемента_   [Подробнее](http://htmlbook.ru/css/transition)

Comment: Интересная вешь, не знал о ней ранее, погуглил, все бы хорошо, но она работает не при нажатии, описано для activ, fokus. Мне же нужно при нажатии на кнопку, делать фильтрацию елементов, я их плавно прячу и показую, но на место спрятаных елементов резко съезжают на их место остальнык, нужно как-то доработать скрипт, что бы это было плавно, но не могу понять как(

Comment: таймеры и анимации в помощь. Есть события animationend, transitionend, к ним можно привязываться, для совершения действий по окончанию анимаций или трансформаций. Например по клику нужно показать один элемент, а другой скрыть, можно сделать css анимацию для этого. Доустим кликаем по кнопке, нужному элементу вешается класс .hiden в котором анимация скрытия, по событию animationend (анимация завершена) на другой элемент вешаем .show

Comment: Покажите скрипт, стили и разметку полностью. Из тог куска что бы предоставили можно только гадать. transition вам в любом случае может помочь, но как его использовать это уже надо решать по месту...

Comment: если вы прячете элементы через display:none; То тогда transition не сработает, но до этого момента можно вертеть различные анимации.

Comment: Показал нужные части кода

Comment: Как на счёт fadeIn() и fadeOut()?
Можно настроить плавность
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp - подробно